# Find the point, that is the closest to the given set of line segments

Tags: python, gradient-descent

The problem seems to be very similar to **Geometric median** problem which can be solved with **Weiszfeld's algorithm**. I've tried to solve my problem using the algorithm but for every new iteration I find new closest points for every segments because they may change as median coordinates change. But it gives incorrect results.

```
from math import sqrt

n = int(input())

segments = []
for _ in range(n):
    coordinates = tuple(int(c) for c in input().split())
    segments.append((coordinates[:3], coordinates[3:]))

median = [0, 0, 0]
for s in segments:
    median[0] += (s[0][0] + s[1][0]) / 2
    median[1] += (s[0][1] + s[1][1]) / 2
    median[2] += (s[0][2] + s[1][2]) / 2
median[0] /= len(segments)
median[1] /= len(segments)
median[2] /= len(segments)

def distance(p1, p2):
    return sqrt(sum((c1 - c2) ** 2 for c1, c2 in zip(p1, p2)))

def dot_product(v1, v2):
    return sum(x * y for x, y in zip(v1, v2))

def subtract_vectors(v1, v2):
    return tuple(x - y for x, y in zip(v1, v2))

def find_closest_point_on_segment(segment, point):
    if distance(segment[0], point) + distance(segment[1], point) == distance(segment[0], segment[1]):
        return point
    
    ap = tuple(c1 - c2 for c1, c2 in zip(point, segment[0]))
    ab = tuple(c1 - c2 for c1, c2 in zip(segment[1], segment[0]))

    cos1 = dot_product(ap, ab) / (distance(point, segment[0]) * distance(segment[1], segment[0]))

    bp = tuple(c1 - c2 for c1, c2 in zip(point, segment[1]))
    ba = tuple(c1 - c2 for c1, c2 in zip(segment[0], segment[1]))
    cos2 = dot_product(bp, ba) / (distance(point, segment[1]) * distance(segment[1], segment[0]))

    if cos1 <= 0:
        return segment[0]
    if cos2 <= 0:
        return segment[1]
    
    return segment[0] if distance(point, segment[0]) < distance(point, segment[1]) else segment[1]

for _ in range(10000):
    points = [find_closest_point_on_segment(s, median) for s in segments]
    distances = [distance(median, p) for p in points]
    for i in range(3):
        # 0.001 is learning rate
        median[i] -= 0.001 * sum((median[i] - p[i]) / d for p, d in zip(points, distances))

print(sum(distance(median, p) for p in points))
```

What may be wrong?

The only input are pairs of 3-dimensional points of segment ends per line.

Comment: This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. It is not possible to provide a specific answer without you providing sufficient information to understand your problem. Please see: [Why is Can someone help me? not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)  for more details.